# How to wait until the importxml is finished loading on Google App Script as code below

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Thank you for your help :)

I would like to wait until newSellPriceFunction and newBuyPriceFunction is finished loading before going to the next steps. As now sometimes it doesn't wait until the loading finished and return data with "Loading...".

```
function GoldPriceNotification() {
  // get the Spreadsheet and sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1oVMpP_MvwX2cUNviJc1NcubBj4ezR0qs2FjHEWfV8ps").getSheetByName("Gold")

  // fetch data to get the price gold price
  var newSellPriceFunction = ss.getRange("C6").setValue("=importxml(D2,E2)");
  var newBuyPriceFunction = ss.getRange("C7").setValue("=importxml(D3,E3)");

  // get value from the previous fetching gold price
  var lastSellPrice = ss.getRange("C2").getDisplayValue();
  var lastBuyPrice = ss.getRange("C3").getDisplayValue();

  // get current date and time
  var date = ss.getRange("B5").setValue("=now()")
  var time = ss.getRange("B5").getDisplayValue();

  // get value from the new gold price (newSellPrice is on the second because it creates span of time while its data is fetching)
  var newBuyPrice = ss.getRange("C7").getDisplayValue();
  var newSellPrice = ss.getRange("C6").getDisplayValue();

  // if the data fetched get "#N/A, clear C6:C7
  if (newSellPrice == "#N/A" || newBuyPrice == "#N/A") {
    ss.getRange("C6:C7").clear()

    // if the data fetched get "Loading...", clear C6:C7
  } else if (newSellPrice == "Loading..." || newBuyPrice == "Loading...") {
    ss.getRange("C6:C7").clear()

    // Check if the last and new prices are different, send Line Notify
  } else if (lastSellPrice != newSellPrice || lastBuyPrice != newBuyPrice) {

    // Copy new Price to the old price area 
    var reNewOldPrice = ss.getRange("C6:C7").copyValuesToRange(ss, 3, 3, 2, 3)


    // Send Line Notify to the group
    var message = "\nเอ็งฮงฮวด สวัสดีค่ะ" + "\nขออนุญาตแจ้งราคาทอง" + "\n⏳ณ " + time + "⏳" + "\nราคาซื้อ:  " + newBuyPrice + "\nราคาขาย: " + newSellPrice + ""
    sendLineNotify(message)

    // Need to clear as sometime when duplicate function. it doesn't show the latest value
    ss.getRange("C6:C7").clear()

    // if the new and old price are the same, clear C6:C7
  } else {
    ss.getRange("C6:C7").clear()
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use a script in your project anyway, why don't you fetch the data with [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=en) instead of using IMPORTXML

Comment: Try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after setting `newSellPriceFunction` and `newBuyPriceFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch data directly in your code without using IMPORTXML formulas with the UrlFetchApp.fetch method. Try this code

```
function ImportXMLData() {
  const url = 'https://www.goldtraders.or.th/default.aspx',
        response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  let content = {
    Sell : '',
    Buy  : ''
  }
  if (response) {
    let html = response.getContentText();
    if (html) {
      content.Sell = html.match(/<span id="DetailPlace_uc_goldprices1_lblBLSell"><b><font color="Red">(.*)<\/font><\/b><\/span>/i)[1];
      content.Buy  = html.match(/<span id="DetailPlace_uc_goldprices1_lblBLBuy"><b><font color="Red">(.*)<\/font><\/b><\/span>/i)[1];
    }     
  }
  return content;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sergey! Thank you a lot. it's really helpful for me:)

Can ask you another little question?
After I try to learn about

"content.Sell = html.match(/<span id="DetailPlace_uc_goldprices1_lblBLSell"><b><font color="Red">(.*)<\/font><\/b><\/span>/i)[1];"

still a bit confused. How match method works Sergey?

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @SedtawootKoolcizoowarn, I'm glad you found my answer helpful. As for the `.match()` method - it is one of the methods of RegExp with which it is very convenient to process a large amount of string data. In your case I try to find everything that is ...<font color="Red">`... in this place ...` <\/font>... Reference [Methods of RegExp and String](https://javascript.info/regexp-methods)

Comment: Oh thank you so much Sergey!. now I just found a little error the on the code as sometimes the number is changed into red and sometimes the number into green.

For example,
<font color="Red">
<font color="Green">

How do we make it ok when process as Red or Green color, Sergey?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi @SedtawootKoolcizoowarn, replace RegExp to `/<span id="DetailPlace_uc_goldprices1_lblBLSell"><b><font color="\w+?">(.*)<\/font><\/b><\/span>/` for _.Sell_ and `/<span id="DetailPlace_uc_goldprices1_lblBLBuy"><b><font color="\w+?">(.*)<\/font><\/b><\/span>/` for _.Buy_

Comment: Thank you Sergey! it does work!. Just know that "\w" meaning inclusion of any words.